# Comparator not sorted my class with dates

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have a class with day,month. I insert random dates and after I sorted it looks like that? Why?

- 1/9
- 2/9
- 3/9
- 7/9
- 9/9
- 10/9
- 5/9
- 11/9

I getting the "time" by getting it from database and i return the data as ArrayList 
Code:

```
public ArrayList<ClockModel> getDay(String workName){
        try {
            open();
            ArrayList<ClockModel> list = new ArrayList<ClockModel>();
            Cursor c = null;
            c = myDb.query(TABLE_DAY, null,"workName = ?", new String[] {workName}, null, null, null);
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Clock clock = new Clock(
                        c.getInt(0), //id
                        c.getString(1),//workName
                        c.getInt(2), //dateDay
                        c.getInt(3),//dateMouth
                        c.getInt(4),//dateYear
                );


                Collections.sort(list,dateCompare); 



                list.add(clock);        
            }       
            return list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }finally{
            close();
        }
    }





    Comparator<ClockModel> dateCompare = new Comparator<ClockModel>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(ClockModel o1, ClockModel o2) {

            int dd1 = o1.getDateDay();
            int mm1 = o1.getDateMonth();

            int dd2 = o2.getDateDay();
            int mm2 = o2.getDateMonth();

            if (mm1 > mm2) {
                return 1;
            } else if (mm1 < mm2) {
                return -1;
            } else { // ==

                if (dd1 > dd2) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (dd1 < dd2) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Works fine with me. sample run http://ideone.com/ynNmrN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compare method looks fine. Are you sure that the bug is exactly here? If it is yours class ClockModel, then I suggest you to double check it=)

And btw, you can simplify your code by using Integer.compare(int, int) like this:

```
Comparator<ClockModel> dateCompare = new Comparator<ClockModel>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(ClockModel o1, ClockModel o2) {

        int monthCompare = Integer.compare(o1.getDateMonth(), o2.getDateMonth());
        int dayCompare = Integer.compare(o1.getDateDay(), o2.getDateDay());

        return (monthCompare != 0) ? monthCompare : dayCompare;

    }
}
```

Comment: If i using the"ublic int compare" what i need to do after?

Comment: +1: yup, his error is not in the code given. Also, good improvement suggestion.

Comment: @Matt Sorry, if I confused you. I just wanted to say that you can simplify your compare method in the anonymous class Comparator<ClockModel> that you have already written. And just as I said it before, I am pretty sure that the bug is not in your Comparator.

Comment: I edited my question look above please maybe you understand the problem

Comment: i solved it my  Collections.sort(list,dateCompare); is before the 
                list.add(clock); that why my last one not sorted thank you :)

Comment: @Matt Why are you sorting the list after each iteration but not after the hole loop? And another unclear point for me is that you always add an element AFTER you have sorted the list.